# Searching through objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have my data structured like this:

```
participants['John Smith'] = {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', id: '1'}
```

Now I have autocomplete input boxes where the participants can just type their first names and then their last names in.

Right now what I do is I have a separate structure to house the first names, another one to house the last names. This is also because Bootstrap's Typeahead needs a "source" so I just put source: first_names.

So basically what happens is that the user types in the first few letters of his name and they can autocomplete, then they select the first few letters of the last name and they can autocomplete, and if their first names and last names match then I would autocomplete the rest of the form. (Right now I'm assuming there are no duplicate names).

I was wondering if I am doing the right thing because it seems too excessive. It works, but is there a better way?

Comment: I think you'd better fix the 'duplicate names' problem first, since that seems like the biggest hole.

Comment: check jLinq js library

Comment: `(Right now I'm assuming there are no duplicate names)`...you can save that assumption by using the `id` to autocomplete the rest of the form instead of the names.

Comment: I personally heavily leverage the underscore library (http://underscorejs.org/) works really nicely for all those iterator functions people write endlessly.

Comment: I think form autocompletion should be left to the browser. This of course depends on what you are trying to do, but I wouldn't want my users to be able to autocomplete a form for another user, which your method would enable.

Comment: Why is `participants` an object instead of an array?

Comment: Thank you everyone. The system I'm building is for a multi-day conference of public school teachers.

@basilikum The form autocompletion is because my "users" are public high school teachers in my country. They take a long time to type and they love it when the system finishes their names for them. There is a tradeoff though in that they can "sign in" other users. No idea how to fix that but we have a physical system too where they fill a sign up sheet. This is more of for logging attendance

Comment: @KyleMuir I've been looking into that. Thanks

Comment: @finishingmove I made it into an array. Sorry bout that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was checking out Underscore and I stumbled into Lodash. I solved it:

```
_.uniq(_.pluck(stuff.participants, 'first_name'))
_.uniq(_.pluck(stuff.participants, 'last_name'))
```

and stuff to that effect. Thanks everyone. I used underscore before but I forgot about it. Guess you really need to code everyday to retain info.

Re: duplicate naming I have to think about it. Last year there was 200 participants, good thing nobody shared the same name. Backend has a unique constraint on 'first_name' and 'last_name'.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload typeahead's methods to do what you need when it searches for a match, below is a basic code example.

So in your case, you can autocomplete the last name if the first name is a single match (and the rest of the form if you think that makes sense, I personally don't)

You could also use the full name as a single entry field and autocomplete both I guess.

```
    $('#searchBox').typeahead(
    {
        source: function (query, process) {  
            process(theArrayToProcess);
        },
        updater: function (item) {
            callAFunctionToDoSomethingWithMatchedItem(item);
            return item;
        },
        matcher: function (item) {
         if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                return true;
         }
        },
        sorter: function (items) {
            return items.sort();
        },
        highlighter: function (item) {
            var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
            return item.replace( regex, "<strong>$1</strong>" );
        },
    });
```